# Why does operator 'in' work in reduce() when it doesn't work in generic 'if' statement?

Tags: javascript, reduce

**Question:** Why does the `in` operator work in `reduce` when it doesn't work inside of a generic `if` statement?

**Example 1**  As expected the `in` operator doesn't log any hits in this test code.  That's because if I understand it correctly [the in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is looking for properties, not values.

```js
"use strict";

var myCreatures;

myCreatures = ['skeleton', 'zombie', 'orc', 'skeleton', 'zombie', 'zombie'];

if ('skeleton' in myCreatures) {
    console.log('true');
}
```

**Example 2**  This is where I get confused.  If the `in` operator is looking for properties why does it work in `reduce()`?  `currentValue` is an argument value and yet this works.

`if (currentValue in accumulator) {}`

```js
"use strict";

var myCreatures = ['skeleton', 'zombie', 'orc', 'skeleton', 'zombie', 'zombie'];

var countedCreatures = myCreatures.reduce( (accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue in accumulator) {
        accumulator[currentValue]++;
    } else {
        accumulator[currentValue] = 1;
    }
    return accumulator;
}, {});
 
console.log(countedCreatures);
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: In the first you're going `string` in `array`. In the accumulator you appear to be doing `string` in `object`.

Comment: Both cases are `if` statements, the fact that the second `if` is inside a `reduce` is only coincidental...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in seems to explain it

Comment: `myCreatures` is an array with numeric indexes, `accumulator` is an object with string keys.